# SQL error - BLOB/TEXT column 'url' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table, but I get this error:

```
SQL error - BLOB/TEXT column 'url' used in key specification without a key length
```

This is the SQL I'm using

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (
url         TEXT  NOT NULL,
name        TEXT  NOT NULL,
pic_url     TEXT  NOT NULL,
vegetarian  INT   NOT NULL,
ingredients TEXT  NOT NULL,
time        INT   NOT NULL,
rating      FLOAT NOT NULL,
ratings_no  INT   NOT NULL,
keywords    TEXT  NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (
    url
)
);
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You may only index the first columns of a TEXT or BLOB column.

```
UNIQUE (url(512))
```

will do the trick, creating an index on the first 512 characters of the column.

**But** you should avoid using `TEXT` columns unless absolutely necessary, and almost never with indexes. They go into separately allocated objects in the DBMS, which makes insertions, updates, and queries slower.  [`VARCHAR(2048)` or a datatype like that will perform better](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html). And stuff like unique indexes work correctly. Please read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html

Notice that URLs work best [when limited to about 2000 characters in length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

Answer (score 1):

BLOB / TEXT are of length 65535. [Indexes in MySQL are considerably less](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html#innodb-maximums-minimums).

Recommend using a `VARCHAR(length)` (latin character set) of a length appropriate to a URL.

Comment: For some `magnet:` URLs `VARCHAR` is sometimes not enough.